# Page Object with dynamic list

Tags: selenium, dynamic, appium, pageobjects

I've a question about best practice for POM (used with appium) and dynamic object's list.

All the "static" objects defined like :

```
 @iOSFindBy(name = UIStrings.ADD)
 @CacheLookup
 private IOSElement addButton;
```

But in my application I've also an item list where the items are dynamic...
The list defined as :

```
 @iOSFindBy(name = UIStrings.MARKET_CELL)
 @WithTimeout(time = 10, unit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
 private List<IOSElement> productList;
```

The problem is , each time I trying to retrieve / add / delete some item from the list , the entire list being updated , which takes lot of time...
I'm also storing some of the list items in some hash for quick retrieve , but the problem is that the hashed elements are referenced to the list , therefore it also trigger the list to more updates ...

Whats is the best practice to use page objects and dynamic elements ?

Thanks